# Boost::ptr_vector changing elements order

Tags: c++, boost

Please, could someone tell me how to switch the location of two elements from the same `ptr_vector` without
new dynamic memory allocation. That is, I want to do the same as below using `std::vector`, but with `boost::ptr_vector`.

Moreover, this has to be done using indexes, instead of `ptr_vector::iterator`.

```
void switch( vector<int>& V , size_t i , size_t j){
    int a  = V[ j ];
    V[ j ] = V[ i ];
    V[ i ] = a;
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

(Untested), I'd imagine it has to be something like:

```
void switch( ptr_vector<int>& V , size_t i , size_t j){
  auto p = V.replace(i, nullptr); // should get you the value there..
  auto k = V.replace(j, p);       // should get you the value there..
  auto res = V.replace(i, k);
  assert(res == nullptr); // this should be the case...
}
```

Comment: Don't call it `switch`

Comment: @Mehrdad how about, make it correct? `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::bad_pointer' what():  Null pointer in 'replace()'`

Comment: @sehe: I upvote things that I think are useful (as the button says). I also don't lose sleep if an answer that says "Untested" happens to throw an error. If you see a problem with an answer and it bothers you then how about fixing it yourself instead of telling me?

Comment: @Mehrdad Says the guy who found the time to inform me that you came up with a different interpretation of the question. This is not "untested". It _cannot_ work because of the design of `ptr_vector`. Believe me, I'd be reading the docs, if I wasn't having to answer your complaints.

Comment: Wow - I missed all the fun... I kept the original (unsuitable name and the semantics of the function...), I should have seen the `nullptr` thing (it's there in the docs now that I look at it...)

Answer (score 2):

```
boost::ptr_vector<T> v;
size_t i = whatever, j = whatever;

// Put this in a separate function
// Do NOT use it as a subexpression or you may (?) forfeit exception safety
v.replace(j, v.replace(i, &v[j]).release()).release();
```

Comment: Now that's a solution. +1 Just for the OP: this is /not/ equivalent to the `std::vector<T>` approach. It's equivalent to a `std::vector<T*>` approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just swap the element values:

```
using std::swap;
swap(v[1], v[2]);
```

This will do exactly what you expected from the std::vector case. Here's a demo using a sentinel type to trace allocations: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36c42e14e9a8e33d)** (it doesn't do any new allocations for the swap)

Prints:

```
static void* X::operator new(size_t)(4)
X::X(int)(1)
static void* X::operator new(size_t)(4)
X::X(int)(2)
static void* X::operator new(size_t)(4)
X::X(int)(3)
static void* X::operator new(size_t)(4)
X::X(int)(4)
X[1] X[2] X[3] X[4] 
===============================
swapping v[1] and v[2]:
X::X(X&&)(X[2])
X& X::operator=(X&&)(X[3])
X& X::operator=(X&&)(X[2])
X::~X()

===============================
X[1] X[3] X[2] X[4] X::~X()
static void X::operator delete(void*)
X::~X()
static void X::operator delete(void*)
X::~X()
static void X::operator delete(void*)
X::~X()
static void X::operator delete(void*)
```

### Full Program

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

struct X {
    X(int i) : _i(i)         { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << i << ")" << "\n"; }
    X(X && x) : _i(x._i)     { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << x << ")" << "\n"; }
    X(X const& x) : _i(x._i) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << x << ")" << "\n"; }
    ~X()                     { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

    void* operator new(size_t n) {
         std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << n << ")" << "\n";
         return ::operator new(n);
    }

    void operator delete(void* px) {
         std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
         return ::operator delete(static_cast<X*>(px));
    }

    X& operator=(X const& x) { 
        _i = x._i;
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << x << ")" << "\n"; 
        return *this;
    }

    X& operator=(X && x) { 
        _i = x._i;
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "(" << x << ")" << "\n"; 
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, X const& x) {
        return os << "X[" << x._i << "]";
    }
    private: int _i;
};

int main()
{
    boost::ptr_vector<X> v;
    v.push_back(new X(1));
    v.push_back(new X(2));
    v.push_back(new X(3));
    v.push_back(new X(4));

    for (auto& p : v)
        std::cout << p << " ";

    std::cout << "\n===============================\nswapping v[1] and v[2]:\n";

    using std::swap;
    swap(v[1], v[2]);

    std::cout << "\n===============================\n";

    for (auto& p : v)
        std::cout << p << " ";
}
```

Comment: @Mehrdad I know exactly which point you mean. However, that point was not made in the question. (OP even explicitly refers to the `std::vector` example, which was given in full.)

Comment: I don't get it. If you understand what the point of the question was then why don't you address it?

Comment: @Mehrdad I do understand the question. I just think the point you deemed essential (because you know what _you_, like me, would use `ptr_vector` for) is **not** the thing the OP was worried about. Read the question closely.

Comment: By the way, can we maybe wait for a response by the OP?